# Nil not compatible with expected argument type 'NSLayoutAnchor<NSLayoutDimention>'

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

this is the problematic code

```
    // auto layout
    let vertivalConstraint = textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.centerYAnchor)
    let leadingConstraint = textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10)
    let trailingConstraint = textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
    let heightConstraint = textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nil, constant: 37)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, vertivalConstraint, trailingConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

let heightConstraint returns the error in the title. How would I go about fixing that.

Thanks

Comment: this is an autocomplete script that was found on github and converted to latest swift. Value is needed to activate NSLayout Contraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
// auto layout
    let vertivalConstraint = textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.centerYAnchor)
    let leadingConstraint = textField.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.leadingAnchor, constant: 10)
    let trailingConstraint = textField.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.codeView.trailingAnchor, constant: -10)
    let heightConstraint = textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 37)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([leadingConstraint, vertivalConstraint, trailingConstraint, heightConstraint])
```

I'm using:

```
.constraint(equalToConstant: 37)
```

instead of:

```
.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: nil, constant: 37)
```